# Django Rest Framework admin extend model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend Django admin model.

This is the code that I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *

from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin

def process_topics(_, __, queryset):
    from person.tasks import calculate_factors
    for object in queryset:
        calculate_factors(object)

process_topics.short_description = "Process topics manually"


class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'sender', 'note',)
    actions = [process_topics, ]

# admin.site.register(Object, ObjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(Object, MarkdownxModelAdmin)
```

I would like to use ObjectAdmin to extend MarkdownxModelAdmin class.

Comment: `class ObjectAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin):` ?

Comment: Thanks! I was confused since I didn't see that `MarkdownxModelAdmin` extends `admin.ModelAdmin`. Thanks! Please write this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer, since there is no accepted answer yet :)

`class ObjectAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin): ...` Should do it.